# How to find all occurrences of a string?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Hi  i have a issue with code am trying but i failed i want to find all text in inner html to excute but my code is getting first line not all in html 
here my code

HTML

```
<a href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/1.mkv">download</a>
<a href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/12.mkv">download</a>
<a href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/13.mkv">download</a>
<a href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/16.mkv">download</a>
<a href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/22.mkv">download</a>
```

Script

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @match        file:///E:/Physics.html
// ==/UserScript==
/* global $ */
(function() {
    var full1 = document.body.innerHTML
  var first1 = full1.indexOf("wwwgoogg");
  var first2 = full1.slice(first1);
  var last1 = first2.indexOf("mkv");
var aa1 = full1.substring((last1-2+first1),(first1));
    alert (aa1);

})();

wwwgoogg.com/asas/1.mkv
wwwgoogg.com/asas/12.mkv
wwwgoogg.com/asas/221.mkv
wwwgoogg.com/asas/133.mkv
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have defined one regex and applied it globally.
for answer please see console

```js
var testStr = "<a href='http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/1.mkv'>download</a> <a href='http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/12.mkv'>download</a> <a href='http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/13.mkv'>download</a> <a href='http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/16.mkv'>download</a> <a href='http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/22.mkv'>download</a>"
var regex = /wwwgoogg/gi;
var result;
var indices = [];
while ((result = regex.exec(testStr))) {
  indices.push(result.index);
}
console.log(indices);
```

Comment: according to my  code am trying to getting next text  what i get only first occurrence wwwgoogg.com/asas/1.mkv  but i want to 
wwwgoogg.com/asas/13.mkv then this 
wwwgoogg.com/asas/12.mkv and so on  you can see my code thanks for reply am trying but not working thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a class="input" href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/1.mkv">download</a>
<a class="input" href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/12.mkv">download</a>
<a class="input" href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/13.mkv">download</a>
<a class="input" href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/16.mkv">download</a>
<a class="input" href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/22.mkv">download</a>
<a class="input" href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/22.mkv">download</a>
<a class="input" href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/22.mkv">download</a>
<a class="input" href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/22.mkv">download</a>
<a class="input" href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/22.mkv">download</a>
<a class="input" href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/22.mkv">download</a>
<a class="input" href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/22.mkv">download</a>
<a class="input" href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/22.mkv">download</a>
<a class="input" href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/22.mkv">download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @match        file:///E:/Physics.html
// @grant        GM_openInTab
// ==/UserScript==
/* global $ */
(function() {
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("input").length;
    var i ;
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  var fields = document.getElementsByClassName("input")[i].getAttribute('href');
GM_openInTab(fields);
  }



    //var bb = document.getElementsByClassName("input")[i].getAttribute('href');
  // GM_openInTab (bb);
})();
```

that's what i want 
thanks a lot for helping me i really  appreciate and I learned a lot and i am learning

Answer (score 0):

You can match the HTML text with a RegExp and get all the results. See the following example:

```js
const text = `
<a href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/1.mkv">download</a>
<a href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/12.mkv">download</a>
<a href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/13.mkv">download</a>
<a href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/16.mkv">download</a>
<a href="http://wwwgoogg.com/asas/22.mkv">download</a>
`;

const matches = text.match(/https?:\/\/wwwgoogg.com\/[\w/.]+/gm);
console.log(matches);
```